# Mazda question re timing chain

Tags: engine, mazda, scheduled-maintenance, timing-chain, preventive-maintenance

How often does a timing chain on a Mazda 3 2013 model need to be changed. At what kms? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The [owner's manual for 2013 Mazda3](https://www.mazdausa.com/siteassets/pdf/owners-optimized/2013/mazda3-4door/2013-mazda3-owners-manual.pdf) specifies two different maintenance schedules:

- Schedule "A" for normal use
- Schedule "B" for severe use

Schedule A, normal use, calls for the **drive belts** every 37,500 mi / 60,000 km.  See page 8-5 [in the manual](https://www.mazdausa.com/siteassets/pdf/owners-optimized/2013/mazda3-4door/2013-mazda3-owners-manual.pdf).

Schedule B, severe use, calls for the **drive belts** every 35,000 mi / 56,000 km.
See page 8-7 [in the manual](https://www.mazdausa.com/siteassets/pdf/owners-optimized/2013/mazda3-4door/2013-mazda3-owners-manual.pdf).

Timing chains are not mentioned.  From what I can see in online discussion, [1](https://www.mazda3forums.com/95-maintenance-care/334249-timing-belt-timing-chain.html),[2](https://www.mazdaforum.com/forum/mazda3-26/timing-chain-question-12759/),[3](https://www.reddit.com/r/mazda3/comments/8rb2ws/new_mazda3_owner_with_timing_beltchain_question/),[4](https://www.mazda3forums.com/66-mazdaspeed/289960-does-mazda-speed-3-have-timing-chain.html) most people believe they are supposed to last the life of the car, or until the engine requires a complete rebuild.

Since Mazda does not specify any required replacement of the timing chain, you should be good for at least 150,000 to 200,000 miles (240,000 to 320,000 km).